# Trying to get a piece of text out of HTML source with webrequest

Tags: c#

So I am making a webrequest and reading to source and all.
In the source there is a particular string that I need to have.
The source:

```
RESPONSIVE.constant.user = {
                id: 71723922,
                name: 'Raktott',
                member: false,
                language: 0,
                isLoggedIn: 1
            };
```

The part that I need is Name: '', So only the part within the ''
How would I accomplish this?
I have tried regular expressions htmlagilitypack etc.

Comment: Can u show the code you have tried?

Comment: I know it is difficult at first. For a moment, pretend you are about to answer a question for someone and you know absolutely nothing about what technology stack they are using, whether it is a desktop application or a web service etc... it helps if you are more specific when you ask a question.

Comment: Can you share the link from which you want to grab that part?

Answer (score 0):

Considering this your string

```
  id: 71723922,
  name: 'Raktott',
  member: false,
  language: 0,
  isLoggedIn: 1
```

What i would do i split the string into string array based on `,` delimiter.

```
string str = "id: 71723922,name: 'Raktott', member: false,language: 0,isLoggedIn: 1";

string[] arrstr = str.Split(',');

for (int i=0; i<=arrstr.Length; i++){

if(arrstr[i].Contains("name"))

{
 string name = arrstr[i];

 //Perform you Logic here

  break;
 }
 }
```

Comment: It is a whole html source this is just a small part that I copied from it.
As this holds the info that I need.

Comment: Still you have a option where you can apply `.Contains` method of string and find out the required values by referring the above code

Comment: Thats a bit confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Regex` with a [lazy quantifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374(v=vs.110).aspx) (`*?`) to capture the text between the `{` curly braces `}`:

```cs
// Don't forget to escape full-stops!
Regex regex = new Regex( @"RESPONSIVE\.constant\.user = {(?<userParams>.*?)}", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);

Match match = regex.Match(pageSourceCode);

if (match.Success)
{
    // Split up the values using comma
    var keyValuePairs = match.Groups["userParams"].Value.Split(',');

    // Split up each line using : as delimeter and clean up both sides, removing whitespace and single quote characters
    var dict = keyValuePairs
        .Select(kvp => kvp.Split(':'))
        .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp[0].Trim(), kvp => kvp[1].Trim().Trim(new char[] { '\'' }));

    // Read name
    var name = dict["name"];

}
```

Comment: Error CS1061 'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'string[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Add `using System.Linq;` to the top of your class.